# How to check if an ASP.Net File Upload Control has a file in JQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

So I'm writing a custom validator and I need to check if a file has been uploaded using the asp.net File Upload Control.

So far I have:

```
function validate(sender, args)
{
    if ($('#<%= hdnID.ClientID%>').val() != "False")
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($('#<%= fup.ClientID %>').val() != '' )
        {
            alert("Run some code here");
        }
        else
        { }
    }
 }
```

The bit that is not right is

```
if ($('#<%= fup.ClientID %>').val() != '' )
```

I'm not sure how to determine whether the control has a file or not.
Any suggestions would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using C# `FileUpload1.HasFile`?

Comment: because the page has other dynamics which would conflict with that. Has to be done in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the JQuery-est way of doing it, but I've had success with something like this:

```
var uploader = $get("<%= fup.ClientID%>");
if (uploader.value != "") {
   //has files
}
```

I also usually check that uploader != null before checking the value. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your id is not correct. The best way I can think of to handle it off the bat would be to add a cssclass to the file input element and call it through that selector

```
<input type="file" class="myClientFileIDWhatever" />

...

if ($('.myClientFileIDWhatever').val() != '') {
```